# SD file system type VFAT is OK?

Tags: sd-card

The instructions say to format the SD card with FAT the one I bought came pre-formatted as VFAT which I believe is just an extension of FAT is this OK or should I load up GParted and format it again?

**EDIT:**
Actually on closer analysis with GParted it is actually FAT32. blkid was calling it VFAT but maybe it calls all the FAT VFAT?

Comment: Which OS distribution are you referring to?

Comment: I took "the one you bought" to mean one from an rpi supplier with an image on it, but now I realize you just meant a plain (pre-formatted, but blank) SD card.  Anyway -- the information is the information ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you bought probably has two partitions.  The first is a small (~50 MB) FAT32 partition.  The second is a larger (2-4 GB) ext4 (linux native) partition.

The FAT32 one is required by the Broadcom SoC, I think.  It contains some kind of simple bootloader and the kernel.  The second one is the root filesystem.

> should I load up GParted and format it again?

Is there a problem with it?

Most (but not all, see comments) OS images for the pi have this two partition set-up, which makes them a bit awkward.  There is no point in formatting the card as a whole.  If you want to replace the OS image, you need to just copy that straight on raw (e.g.,  in linux using `dd`).

Comment: It's almost 8GB of VFAT but no there is no problem I just wanted to check first if it was OK before I install and I haven't really decided on a distro yet. I use Ubuntu so maybe I will stick with Debian (Rasibian or whatever it's called) but I kind of want to try Arch too.. indecisive. I'll probably use NOOBS since its my first one.

Comment: Actually on closer analysis with GParted it is actually FAT32. blkid was calling it VFAT but maybe it calls all the FAT VFAT?

Comment: You're right, it is FAT32.  I'll change that.  It really doesn't matter how a card is formatted if you are copying an OS image onto it.

Comment: Beware that the reason it doesn't matter is because the `.iso` *should not* go into a formatted partition.  The image contains partitions and the partition table already.  It needs to be copied raw straight to the device.

Comment: Does that depend on whether I use NOOBS or not though?

Comment: I think with NOOBS you just format and copy. It self installs the OS. If I choose to just install the .iso myself then ya. That's what I got from the github readme https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Based on this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/quick-start-guide-v2_1.pdf -> Yes that is different.  In this case you are apparently unpacking into a formatted partition.

Comment: OK, cool I will probably do that first my try of the device. Thanks for all your help I would have upvoted much more of your comments and answers but I don't have the reputation yet so accepting the answer was all the karma I could give you.